# In SQL Server 2008 ,is it possible to disable auto drop of global temp table

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Question 1: I am using a global temp tables in SQL Server 2008. But once my connection is closed this temp is dropped. Is there any way to disable auto drop

Question 2: If two connections are accessing same global temp table and another connection is 
trying to delete that global temp table, does SQL Server handles this synchronization properly?

Answer (score 3):

You can create your global temp tables in a stored procedure and mark it with the startup option.

SQL Server maintains a reference count greater than zero for all global temporary tables created within startup procedures.

some example code

```
CREATE PROC dbo.CreateGlobalTempTables
AS
CREATE TABLE ##my_temp_table
(
   fld1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   fld2 INT NULL
);
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_procoption 'dbo.CreateGlobalTempTables', 'startup', 'true';
```

The global temporary table will be created automatically at startup and persist until someone explicitly drops it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a table to persist beyond the death of the connection that created it, you should just create a regular table instead of a temporary one.  It can still be created in tempdb directly (geting you the benfits of simple logging and auto destruction on server restart) but it's name wouldn't be prefixed by ##.

DROP TABLE is a transactional statement that will block if there are any active connections using that table (with locks).

Answer (score 1):

When the connection that created the ##GlobalTempTable ends, the table will be dropped, unless there is a lock against it.

You could run something like this from the other process to keep the table from being dropped:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT TOP 1 FROM ##GlobalTempTable WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)


...COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

However, when the transaction ends, the table will be dropped.  If you can't use a transaction like this, then you should use a permanent table using the [Process-Keyed Table method](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#prockeyed).

Comment: In addition to keeping the table alive, wouldn't this also prevent any other connection from reading (let alone updating) whichever random record gets selected by the TOP 1. The lock may even escalate from a row to a page, extent or even table lock prevent even more data from being accessed. That may not be desirable!  I'm not sure but if there is no data in the table when this is issued, no locks will be held.

Comment: this would all depend on the implementation of the ##globaltemp table. possibly each process has its own block of rows? OP never explains.  I'll bet the real solution is to use something than  ##globaltemp table, like the [Process-Keyed Table method](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#prockeyed) that I link to in my answer.