# Can un-dropped temp tables cause run away memory consumption in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say we have some poorly written SQL that does not release temp tables when done, or well written SQL that gets killed *after* it creates temp tables but *before* it drops them.

Could this result in a SQL Server instance sucking up a lot of memory and not releasing it?  How would I reclaim this memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a temp table will be dropped after it gets out of scope...and I am talking about a local temp table here not a global one (with 2 pound signs)

SQL Server will always suck up a lot of memory, it will put as much data in cache as possible, getting data from RAM is 1000 times faster than getting data from disk

Run this in SSMS

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTemp(id INT)
GO
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#MyTemp%'
```

Now close that window in SSMS

run this in another window

```
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#MyTemp%'
```

Is the table still there?

If the table is created in a proc, it is not there when the proc is done

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prtestTemp
AS 
CREATE TABLE #temp(id INT)

SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#Temp%'

GO
```

Run proc

```
EXEC prtestTemp
```

Now run this, table is not there

```
SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#Temp%'
```

Comment: Any ideas on global `##` tables? I know what the docs say `Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.` but that appeared to be wrong when [I've tested this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748710/normal-table-or-global-temp-table/4748753#4748753)

Comment: AFAIK (and I don't really use global temp tables) they will be around until you restart or the table gets dropped

Comment: Martin, I just tested, I created a ##temp table in one window, closed the window, opened another window, did `SELECT * FROM ##temp` and got this..`Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '##temp'.`  don't remember this being the case in the past